# Слово "заскорузлый"

Tags: словообразование, этимология

Слово "заскорузлый" не очень понятен корень, и что обозначает? Происхождение слова.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В современном языке слово **заскорузлый** имеет следующий состав: заскоруз(корень) - л (суффикс)- ый(окончание) (источник - Словообразовательный словарь Тихонова). С суффиксом как раз все понятно: это старый суффикс причастия прошедшего времени (ср.: загрубе**л**ый, загорелый и пр.), который в современном языке стал суффиксом глагольных форм прошедшего времени.

Значений у слова **заскорузлый** несколько: 1) шершавый, загрубелый (о коже, коре и т. п.); 2) *разг.* ставший жёстким от высохшего пота, грязи и т. п. (об одежде, ткани и т. п.); 3) *перен., разг.* грубый, чёрствый, бесчувственный, нечувствительный (о человеке); 4) *перен., разг.* невосприимчивый к новому; косный (о человеке).

Что касается происхождения, то это собств. русское слово. В словарях фиксируется с XIX в. Представляет собой перешедшее в прилагательные причастие с суф. -л- (как мерзлый) глаг. **заскорузнути** «загрубеть». Этот глаг. образован с прист. за- со знач. завершенности действия (как застыть) от *скурузнути* «черстветь, грубеть, коряветь», производного с суф. -ну-ти от утрач. **скорузъ** «нечто огрубелое, засохшее», в свою 
очередь производного с суф. -уз-ъ от **скора** «шкура». Суфикс **-уз-ъ** встречается, например, в диал. *мелуз* «мелкие высевки». (Источник - Этимологический словарь Цыганенко).

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: Я имел в виду исторический суффикс -узл- или -УЗ-
Его-то никакими причастиями не объяснить.
Вот "скорузь" объясняет само слово. Хотя суффикс по-прежнему загадочен.

Comment: Интересно, что в у Даля упоминается слово **руз**, которое значит "рубище, будничная, простая одежонка", то есть вещь **грубая**, **плотная** и, возможно, **грязная**. Может быть, **уз** не суффикс, а часть корня? Была какая-нибудь "скорорузь" ("грубая кожа"), потом элизия и всё такое. Но это так, мысли вслух.

Answer (score -1):

В тех словарях, что под рукой, слово не нахожу.
Но думаю, что в основе морф "кор" - кора, скорлупа и т.д.
Вот суффикс необычный... Попробую найти что-нибудь. Или народ подскажет.

(+)
10.05.2015
заскорузлый
    за(с)кору́злый (о руках), напр. у Мельникова; укр. закору́злий наряду с закору́блий – то же; восходит к болг. кору́ба "дуплистое, пустое дерево, дупло", согласно Мi. ЕW (132) и Бернекеру (1, 577). Далее ср. кора́.
(Фасмер)